Calling a bash script from Gitlab CI
I have no ideas what I am doing wrong. Just running this simple bash script on my pipeline. It also does not work when I test it locally. Same error.
refresh.sh
#!/bin/sh
# refresh.sh
# Create a kustomization.yaml and then add all kubernetes YAMLs into resources...
echo -n "
# built by ./refresh.sh
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
" > kustomization.yaml

yamls=$(find . -type f -name "*.yaml" | grep -v kustomization.yaml)

for y in ${yamls[@]}; do
  kustomize edit add resource $y
done

Error:
./refresh.sh: line 16: syntax error: bad substitution

my .gitlab-ci.yml
image:
  name: openpolicyagent/conftest:latest

stages:
  - kustomize
  - policy

kustomize:
  stage: kustomize
  script:
    - echo "Running test 1..."
    - chmod +x refresh.sh
    - ./refresh.sh

policy:
  stage: policy
  script:
    - echo "Running test 2"
    - kubectl kustomize | conftest test -
    - rm kustomization.yaml

Also I can see my script listed on my current directory on the logs when I add ls -al in the pipeline kustomize stage so not sure what the issue is:
$ ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxrwx    8 root     root           167 May  2 18:11 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root            44 May  2 18:11 ..
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root           128 May  2 18:11 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1020 May  2 18:11 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          9140 May  2 18:11 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root            76 May  2 18:11 policy
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           375 May  2 18:11 refresh.sh
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root            38 May  2 18:11 staging

Thanks

Try using the full path to the script instead of depending on the current directory.

BTW, using echo -n is problematic, especially with /bin/sh -- the POSIX spec for echo explicitly describes output as undefined when -n is present. printf '%s' "..." is a more portable and reliable alternative to echo -n "..."; see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

Please remove the bash tag. There is no bash involved in your code.

I'd try this and check the output. It's probably some path issues.
kustomize:     
stage: kustomize
script:
- pwd  # Print current working directory
- ls -la  # List all files in the current directory
- echo "Running test 1..."
- chmod +x refresh.sh
- ./refresh.sh


See latest comment ^

"Snippets" are only for code that can be run inside a web browser. Use the {} button, not the snippet button, for everything that isn't HTML/JS/CSS.

syntax error: bad substitution is certainly not a path issue.

The author of the question edited it. The initial error was file not found.

Ah. FYI, @Tate_87, editing questions in ways that invalidates preexisting answers isn't allowed, and if nobody had added an answer to the new form of the question before this came to attention I would have rolled back your question to its original version and asked you to add a new/separate question for your new/separate problem.

Totally agree and apologies for the confusion. Copy that moving forward :)
